# How to assign pointer to global variable?

Tags: c, string, global-variables

I have to split up a command line argument in order to determine the file type.  In order to do this, I'm using

```
char fileName; //global variable, just below function prototypes

char *fileType;

fileType= strtok(inputFile, "."); //first string split
fileName= (int) &fileType; //store the file name for further use

fileType= strtok(NULL, "."); //get the file type
```

The tokenizer function is working, but in the interest of keeping redundant code to a minimum, I want to store the filename, as I will have to create a new file with the same name, but different extension later on.

In the debugger, the the fileName variable never gets used.  Why?

Comment: Why are you casting the address of fileType to an integer?! Is it just for the compiler to stop complaining.

Comment: basically, thats it.  I get an integer from pointer without cast warning otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About

```
char fileName; //global variable, just below function prototypes
```

if `fileName` is supposed to be a string then it must be a pointer to the first `char` in that string (i.e. `char *fileName`).

if `fileName` is suposed to be a *pointer to* a string, then it should be declared as `char **fileName`.

---

About

```
char *fileType;
```

if this is a local variable, and `fileName` is a pointer to it, then after the function return it will be destroyed and the pointer will point to unknown data.

---

About

```
fileName= (int) &fileType; //store the file name for further use
```

this seem non-sense to me. Why cast the address of `fileType` to an integer? I guess the compiler complained because `fileName` is a `char` and not a `char *` and you noticed this would fix the error. Don't do this kind of fixes without understanding what you're doing, because programming like that just leads to esoterical code which must probably won't work as intended anyway.

So, if `fileName` is defined as `char *` then just do `fileName = fileType`. Else, if `fileName` is declared as `char **` then do `fileName = &fileType`;

---

About

```
fileType= strtok(NULL, "."); //get the file type
```

if `strtok()` can return a pointer to a *new* string, and `fileName` is declared as `char *`, then whatever you stored previously in it wouldn't be meaningful anymore. In this case `fileName` would need to be a `char **` (a pointer to a string) which I proposed in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `char` array along with `strcpy`.

Like this:

```
#define MAX_FILENAME_SIZE 200
char fileName[MAX_FILENAME_SIZE];

int f()
{
    fileType = strtok(inputFule, ".");
    // then use strcpy
    strcpy(fileName, fileType);

}
```

A `char` global would only store **one** character.

Comment: It was the string copy addition that helped out.  I was trying to assign the variable directly, without using the function.  Is that still possible?

Comment: You can't just assign. You **need** to use `strcpy` in your case since the string returned by `strtok` needs to be copied into the heap. I would **strongly** recommend you use `char fileName[200]`. If it's working with just `char fileName`, it does not mean it will always work. REMEMBER: `char fileName` only guarantees you enough space for **one** `char`.

Comment: Understood.  Shifting from Java to C is quite interesting, makes me feel like I'm back in Intro to Programming!

Comment: in that case, you may as well use strncpy and/or check the length of fileType, especially if inputFule is controlled by the user.

Comment: Downvoted for the *strong* recommendation to use bad programming practices such as arbitrary constant buffer sizes and `strcpy`.  Do what BatchyX said instead.